# Copy to directory outside of project directory using Gradle 4.0.2

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a gradle build which generates war file. I want to copy war file to my application servers' dropins directory which is somewhere outside of project directory. I have following copy task to do this.

```
task copyWarToDropins(type: Copy,dependsOn:[war]) {
    from './build/libs/bds-service-token-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war'
    into file('/apps/dropins') // want to copy to 'C:/apps/dropins' directory
    rename { fileName -> 'bds-service-token.war' }
} 

build.dependsOn copyWarToDropin
```

It evaluates /apps/dropins relative project directory and does copy there. I have tried many ways I can think of but could not make it copy to C:/apps/dropins directory.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, please note that using `into file(...)` is redundant, as each call to `into(...)` will be evaluated via `Project.file(...)` anyhow.

As you can read in [the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#file-java.lang.Object-) , `file(...)` handles strings in the following way:

> - A CharSequence, including String or GString. Interpreted relative to the project directory. A string that starts with `file:` is treated as a file URL.

So, one way to solve your problem could be using an absolute file URL.

However, if you continue to read the documentation, you will see that Java `File` objects are supported. So you could simply create such an object:

```
into new File('C:/your/absolute/path')
```